# Does Fermat's Last Theorem state that $a\not=b\not=c$?

Tags: number-theory

From what I've read on Fermat's Last Theorem (FLC), it states that

$$\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb{N},\nexists n>2$$

for

$$a^n+b^n=c^n$$

I haven't, however, found any source say that $a\not=b\not=c$ (in the Theorem's context) has to hold. Is that implied by using different variables $a,b,c$? Would finding a solution where

$$\exists [(n>2)\wedge(a,b,c)\wedge(a=c\vee a=b\vee b=c)]$$

satisfied FLC lead to FLC being disproven?

Comment: Since in this context $\mathbb{N}$ is used to denote the strictly positive integers, it is easy to show that no solution can have $a = b$ or $b = c$ or $c = a$. Apart from that fact, **if** one found a solution with two of the bases equal, that would indeed disprove the conjecture. The case of two of $a,b,c$ equal is not ruled out by the notation.

Comment: @DanielFischer I believe it could be an answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer Which *conjecture* are you refering to? The T in FLT is jsutified in our times.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Fermatsche Vermutung, Satz von Wiles (et al.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One would never find such solution. *Proof*: if $a=b$, then $a^n+a^n=c^n$ therefore $2a^n=c^n$, taking the $n^{\rm th}$ root yields $\sqrt[n]{2}a=c$. Dividing both sides by $a$ will leave us with $\sqrt[n]{2}=\tfrac ca$. But one can show that $\sqrt[n]{2}$ is irrational for every $n\geqslant3$. Thus the equation has no solution. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$ The notation $\forall a,b,c\in\Bbb N$ doesn't rule out the possibility that $a=b$ or $a=c$ or $b=c$. Since it means that for any arbitrary strictly positive integers the equation wont have a solution, and that includes the case you mentioned. One can replace that notation with $\forall(a,b,c)\in\Bbb N^3$, which means that we can take any triplet from $\Bbb N^3$, and that includes the triplets $(1,1,1)$, $(2,2,2)$, $(3,3,3)$, ...

Comment: I would accept, except for the fact that I also proposed for $a=c$ or $b=c$.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien One can show that too using the same argument.

Comment: @Hakim Well, by an even easier argument, since no positive integer equals $0$.

Comment: You're right. ${}$